# Java: Call Method when Program can't Connect

Tags: java, database

We are creating a message sending program in java that connects to an existing service running at a specific server.

It frequently checks if it can send and receive data from the url of the server.

If the connection is alive, the program can send messages to the url and log them into a database until a response for that message is received.

But once the connection is lost, the database should be cleared of all messages, since the other side also clears the messages received.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: can you post the code you're using to connect/receive connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you will get an exception when the connection is lost.
You should catch that exception, and in the exception you can clear your messages

Comment: In case if are not getting exception (I guess you should by the way), you can define a timeout and if there is no response after the specified time, you can send the message again and reset the timeout. If you don't get the response again you can clear it from the db. This will work on a message basis, so you have to clear all messages one by one or you can assume if some predefined number of responses have not arrived, the connection is lost and you can clear all messages. However it is better to handle them as @Shervin suggested.